# Laravel-backpack; how to sort dropdown entries when using a field to enter a related id?

Tags: laravel-backpack

Classic example: each post has a user_id

in the creation operation, I added a field using the `user` relationship a field_name and backpack created for me a dropdown where to select a user name.

Fantastic, but, usernames are not in alphabetic order.
How can I sort entries in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved (as documented)

I added `options` to the field definition

```
'options'   => (function ($query) {
    return $query->orderBy('username', 'ASC')->get();
}),
```